# Ввод с клавиатуры, если это число писать "Это число", если не число писать"Это не число"

Tags: python

Ввод с клавиатуры, если это число писать "Это число", если не число писать "Это не число".
У меня не получилось, т.к. input() присваивает только тип str, а int(input()) только int. Мне нужно чтобы было и то и другое.

Comment: В первую очередь в метках вопроса нужно указывать язык программирования/используемые технологии

Comment: @Dev18 эвристически по характерному фрагменту кода

Comment: А вообще была толпа уже подобных вопросов

Comment: Интересно, кто это не пожалел трех баллов репы и проминусовал все ответы на вопрос?

Answer (score 4):

А можно обработать через исключение:

```
user_input = input("Введите значение: ")

try:
    number = float(user_input)
    print("Это число")
except ValueError:
    print("Это не число")
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае будет лучше использовать встроенный метод `.isdigit()`, однако он работает только для неотрицательных чисел (тип `int`)

```
a=input()
if a.isdigit(): #проверяем, является ли строка записью целого числа
    print('Число')
else:
    print('Не число')
```

В одну строчку:

```
print('Число' if input().isdigit() else 'Не число')
```

Comment: -1 целое число?

Comment: @АлексейР прошу прощения, неотрицательных)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```py
def checker(num):
    if num[0] == '-' and len(num) > 1: num = num[1:]
    if all(i.isdecimal() for i in num.split('.')) and len(num.split('.')) in [1, 2]:
        print("Это число")
    else:
        print("Это не число")

    
>>> print(checker('123'))
Это число
>>> print(checker('1.23'))
Это число
>>> print(checker('1.23.23'))
Это не число
>>> print(checker('1b'))
Это не число
```

Comment: Во-первых советую вам всё-таки переносить строку после if'а - будет понятней. Во-вторых - может быть вы имели в виде `num = num[1:]` вместо `num = num[1]`?

Comment: А вообще-то код какой-то странный: откуда `return`? почему после else'а просто строка? в первом if'е - почему-то `=`. в вызове `all` - ошибка `AttributeError`... куда торопимся?

Comment: @wchistow, спасибо за замечания, поправил. Действительно торопился, не хотел пропустить простой вопрос) Постараюсь быть внимательнее.

Comment: `AttributeError` всё-таки остался...

Comment: @wchistow, поправил `AttributeError`, добавил тесты.

Comment: Нет, вы определённо очень спешите - на этот раз забыли кавычки :)

Comment: @wchistow, где, в тестах? Нет, не забыл. У меня питон ответы в интерпретаторе без кавычек пишет.

Comment: Да, в тестах - в вызове `checker`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150390/discussion-between--and-wchistow).